# PHP Extending class makes children inherit same static property

Tags: php, static, singleton, properties, factory

I'd like to start by showing a test case:

```
class A {
    public static $instance=null;
    public function __construct(){
        self::$instance=$this;
    }
    public function className(){
        return get_class(self::$instance);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function className(){
        return get_class(self::$instance);
    }
}

// test code
$b=new B();
echo $b->className; // B
$a=new A();
echo $a->className; // A
echo $b->className; // A <- error: not B any more!
```

**Notes**

- I'm using a factory+singleton patterns above. Well, somewhat.
- I don't need any specs on "implementing patterns correctly". I need problem solving, not KISS violations ;).
- Critics might say A should be an interface. Ideally, that's what it should have been, but it's just a simple class, sorry.

The issues lies in the fact that `self::$instance` is the same for all instances. How do I separate `self::$instance` for each class?

**Edit:** I've had this idea:

```
$GLOBALS['store']=array();
class A {
    public static $instance=null;
    public function __construct(){
        $GLOBALS['store'][__CLASS__]=$this;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what static means. They are ALL using the same variable. So any change will change the variable.

Comment: I'm not sure if `__CLASS__` is determined at run-time ... IMO it will always be 'A'.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are trying to do. Once you added extra info to the question that made that clear, it stopped being half-witted itself.

Comment: @giraff: `__CLASS__` is determined at compile time...  If you want to use late static binding (5.3+), use `static::$foo` instead of `self::$foo`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store an instance per class name:

```
class A { 
    public static function getInstance(){
        // Maybe use this function to implement the singleton pattern ...
        return self::$instance[get_called_class()];
    }

    public function className(){
        return get_class(self::getInstance());
    }   
}
```

Comment: `get_called_class()` is exactly what I needed in order to avoid having to mess up child classes' code.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this the clean way. 
 That is one of the mayor drawbacks on stati propertys: you cannot overrride them.

But you wantet an sollution so.....here is the worarround:
use __calllStatic

```
  <?php 
 class A {
    public static function __callstatic($name,$args)
    {
        if($name="getClass"){
                return 'A';
        }
    }
 }

 class  B extends  A{
 public static function __callstatic($name,$args)
    {
        if($name="getClass"){
                return 'B';
        }
    }
 }


echo  A::getClass();
echo  B::getClass();
?>
```

the output of this is "AB";

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `public static $instance=null;` declaration in class B.

```
class A {
    public static $instance=null;
    public function __construct(){
        self::$instance=$this;
    }
    public function className(){
        return get_class(self::$instance);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static $instance=null;
    public function className(){
        return get_class(self::$instance);
    }
}

// test code
$b=new B();
echo $b->className(); // B
$a=new A();
echo $a->className(); // A
echo $b->className(); // Now returns B, as desired.
```

Comment: I was aware of this (should have described it in the post). The issue with this is that class B would need to have "unnecessary code" to accommodate class A. Although usable, it's a bit inconvenient since `::$instance` was supposed to be "internal" anyway. +1 for the idea though; clearly shows OOP behaviour.