# Have PHP child classes inherit separate instances of a static property

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

The title is maybe not too clear, so here's an example.

```
abstract Class A {
    public static $property = null;
}

Class B extends A {

}

Class C extends A {

}
```

I want to have a "None" method in all classes extending A, and this method should return an instance - *always the same* - of the *called* class. So:

```
B::None()  // Returns a "default" B
C::None()  // Returns a "default" C
```

**Why is this**: I have (simplifying) several Slots which may or may not be assigned to Activities of several kinds. So I can have a Slot for Surfing and one for Swimming. And that Slot may be null. In my code, when reporting, I could of course do something like

```
if (Slot.Surfing == null) {
    println "Not surfing anywhere";
} else {
    println Slot.Surfing.Location;
}
```

But I'd like to not check at all and just write

```
println Slot.Surfing.Location;
```

and pre-assign the slot to Surfing::None(). Actually I'd do that in a superclass and have it automatically assign the "proper" instance of None.

This way, Slot.Surfing(nowhere) is a *different null* from Slot.Swimming(nowhere), but that for me now would actually be a *feature*.

The problem is that if I really want to check I'm swimming *somewhere*, I must be sure that

```
if (Slot.Surfing == Surfing::None()) {
```

works. For that, None() must always return the same object. I could run the check on a field of Surfing, maybe a non-i18n-ed integer value... 0 or -1 being a typical choice... but adding a property for that purpose seems ill designed.

**NOTE**: this has many similarities with the Singleton (anti)pattern, but it is not actually a Singleton (see at bottom).

If I implement the `None()` method in A, though, I have to handle the fact that any static property will "live" only once, in A, and not in each of the child classes. So I create a default instance of B, save it in A, and then all subsequent calls to *other* subclasses of A will find and return that one instance -- and `C::None()` will be an instance of B.

I can make the None() method create a *new* default instance every time. This works, but now I have several "default" Bs, and in some circumstances two properties both set to `B::None()` will be, quite correctly, considered *different*.

In the end I came up with this workaround (PHP 5.3.+):

```
private static $nones = array(); // array of already created "null" instances

protected static function None() {
    // If I do not already have an instance for this class...
    if (!isset(self::$nones[$ChildName = get_called_class()])) {
        // ... I create a default instance.
        self::$nones[$ChildName] = new $ChildName(/*...*/);
    }
    // And I return the default instance.
    return self::$nones[$myClass];
}
```

I have checked [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203810/is-there-a-way-to-have-php-subclasses-inherit-properties-both-static-and-instan) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847810/php-setting-inherited-static-property-will-also-set-it-in-other-classes-inheri) on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, and [the most relevant one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472195/php-extending-class-makes-children-inherit-same-static-property) employs what amounts to the same approach (notice the `$instance` array indexed on the called class's name):

```
class A { 
    public static function getInstance(){
        // Maybe use this function to implement the singleton pattern ...
        return self::$instance[get_called_class()];
    }

    public function className(){
        return get_class(self::getInstance());
    }   
}
```

Yet maybe because I'm still a wet-behind-the-ears OOPer, to me this approach smells. I would think there ought to be a way of declaring a child static property in the parent, and accessing it from the superclass (of course, then I would have to ask myself: *if A declares a "downstream" static property, B inherits from A, and C from B, where does that property live, or where should it live, now?* -- and I have no satisfying answer).

### Addendum - Singletons

The above approach is in practice not too different from a `Singleton`. It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596323/1607098) (thanks to Touki for pointing me there) that I can get rid of Singletons through dependency injection. Yet in this case it would require to pass around, say, `None_C` to all methods that may require a default value for a reference to an instance of C. I would then have to push `None_C` into my `Configuration` object, and have it know about any subclasses of A that I might declare. At first sight, this smells even more (although in fact *adding another subclass of A* amounts to changing the system's configuration... which would be *the* reason for changing `Configuration`).

### TL;DR

So to make a long story short, granted that the above approach **does** work,

- is having the parent class maintain a static array of its "active" children acceptable from an OOP point of view?
- is there a better and/or cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Did you check http://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php - aka using `static::` keyword instead of `self::`

Comment: Singletons aren't [acceptable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4596323/1607098) from an *"OOP point of view"*

Comment: @VladPreda, yes, I did, but it didn't work - I was still referring to a single global instance of the A::$none property.

Comment: @Touki, I was going to say that it is one of the classical Patterns, but on reading your link I see it's being doubted by none other than Erich Gamma. I'll look into this dependency thingie. Even if it might not pan out, my thanks!

Comment: You have described pretty well what you have tried, but not how this is actually used within a bigger picture. Without that, it would be hard to give proper advice.

Comment: @Jack thanks for the interest. I've added a "Why is this?" section in my question, trying to boil it down as much as I could.

Comment: Oh, you want to implement null objects? :)

Comment: Um... yes? :-) (tried to google for that, found nothing useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory is not an objection (nowadays, it rarely is), the solution is simply to get a step further into OOP land.

The real problem for which the "child singleton" was needed was that *I wanted comparisons to be reliable*. Of course two different "nulled" objects, while being both "nulled" and therefore identical in this respect, are *not* the same object. If they have identical *properties* too, then the `==` operator will return TRUE, but if one of them gets slightly changed for some reason (i.e., due to a bug), `==` will return FALSE. The use of `===` PHP5 operator in singleton context will solve this problem, but introduces more complexity.

The (not so obvious to me) simple solution is to *discard comparisons altogether* and simply replace:

```
if (Slot->Surfing == Surfing::None())
```

with a suitable

```
Slot->Surfing->isNull() // or maybe isEmpty() depending on semantics
```

Then I can declare the isEmpty method in the *parent* class, and this reveals that I really needed also a more specific *[equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947536/php-overload-equals-operator)* and *comparison* operators:

```
abstract Class A {
    ...
    public static function createNull() {
        $nulled = new A();
        $nulled->setNull();     // Whatever is needed to nullify an object
        return $nulled;
    }

    public function setNull() {
        $this->nullFlag = true; // Example
        return $this;
    }

    public function isNull() {
        return (true === ($this->nullFlag)); // Or whatever else
    }
    
    abstract function equals($obj);
    abstract function compareTo($obj);
}

Class Surfing extends A {
    public function equals($obj) {
        if (null == $obj) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($this === $obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!($obj instanceOf Surfing)) {
            return false;
        }
        // Properties
        foreach(array('property1','property2',...) as $val) {
            if ($this->$val !== $obj->$val) {
                return false;
        }
        // Maybe some other check
        ...
        return true;
    }
}

...

Slot->Surfing = Surfing::createNull();

...

if (Slot->Surfing->isNull()) {
    ...
}
```

An additional big advantage of this approach is that now every activity is an independent object and *can* be safely updated without altering other instances (if `Slot->Surfing` was a nulled object, to set it to something else I needed to reassign, I couldn't simply go ahead and modify it -- this actually introduced horrid coupling and had a tremendous potential for subtle bugs).